# Mac OS Classic install error "the installer document is unusable for installation [...]" (original disks message)

Tags: mac-os-classic, m68k

Attempting to upgrade Mac OS Classic 7.5.0 to 7.5.3 via floppies that have been tested successfully on a Performa 460... but things fail ominously on my IIsi with "This is not the correct "⟨SrcDisk⟩" disk. Make sure you are using the original Installer disks and try again. Click Continue if you have the correct disk to insert. Click Stop to stop any further installation."

[image: eIIsi install failure]

Some kind of copy protection? What gives, these install floppies just worked yesterday on a Performa 460 just fine, where is this error coming from?

Comment: Different installers for different models?

Comment: I don't think so - the advanced mode installer lets you select the system, both are listed. I installed in easy mode however (let the installer decide), I may as well try and force it... will let you know what happens.

Comment: Selecting the narrow IIsi system set generates the same error. No difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error in this case turned out to be a degrading floppy disk drive.

Unreliable reads from the floppy caused the arcane error message.

Comment: What you need to understand about the drive is that it is unlikely bad but rather out of calibration. Floppy drives are not precision devices and if the heads are on one edge of the track area, while the disks were written with a drive whose heads are on the other side of the track area, you will get similar errors. Neither drive is 'bad'

Answer (score 4):

There is no copy protection in System 7.5.x. Even in the era of its original release, Apple distributed it for free on the Internet.

The [Apple Installer 4.0.3 Error Guide](https://mac68k.info/forums/servlet/JiveServlet/download/3-316-1206-206/Installer%20Error%20Guide.pdf) p.10 gives this description for the "The installer document [...] is unusable for installation" error message:

> This error occurs when the Installer is unable to find a required
> resource specified in the installer script - 'inrl', 'inpk', 'infa',
> etc., has become corrupted, or the resource map has become corrupted.
> This error has also been known to occur due to the following reasons.
>
> 1. Two packages are included for installation which involve conflicting actions. One package calls for the installation of a file
>    or resource, and the other package calls for it's deletion, if it
>    exists.
> 2. The same source resource is specified for installation as two different resources under separate resource ID's. In other words,
>    there are 2 'inra' resource which reference the same source resource,
>    but specify different target resources.

From the description, it sounds like the several possible causes can lead to the error, maybe corruption of the Installer Document itself (in the Installer-related resources), or maybe corruption of some other resource or file they reference, besides the numbered installer design errors noted.

The most obvious cause would be data corruption, either of the disk itself, or due to some hardware problem with the machine that causes it not to be able to read the disk correctly (malfunctioning floppy drive, logic board, RAM, etc.)

The `inrl` resource contains "Installer Rules", logic which is specified in a kind of scripting language and the installer will use to implement automated behaviour such as for Easy Install and which can include actions for specific machines. (See [Apple Installer 4.0.8. Technical Guide](https://mac68k.info/forums/servlet/JiveServlet/download/3-316-1206-207/Installer%204.0.8%20Technical%20Guide.pdf), p.80).

This is speculation, but due to the parts of the installer that this error is related to being possibly machine specific, maybe there is corruption in a part that just isn't used in the installation on the Performa 460 and so didn't come up there.

Someone who has the capability to figure out the details of the Installer Rules from the binary compiled versions in the `inrl` resources may be able to shed some light on what's present on the IIsi and absent on the Performa 460 or vice versa.

Comment: In case you're short of workarounds, a thing to try to rule out hardware disk causes would be to try mounting Disk Copy images of the installation disks instead of using actual floppies, though you'll need a spare disk/partition to have them on during the installation and some way to transfer them on (CD-ROM, network, serial, etc.)

Comment: It might be a good idea to put all helpful information into the answer, not part in comment.

Comment: Is there a way to check for corruption? A checksum of some kind? Are parts archived/compressed with a tool that can check them? Is there a way to get a debug console during installation?

Comment: @hippietrail I don't know if there's a _good_ way to do that; my bad way, which only works for write-protected disks where you're not expecting any changes at all, would be to image any physical disks back on different machines with Disk Copy and compare the checksums Disk Copy reports with the other machines and with the checksums of known good copies of the images

Comment: @rakslice: I remember back in the day my original install disks for my Amiga 1000 (or maybe my A2000) had one flipped bit that I ended up tracking down manually. That's when the disks were new. 35-year-old floppies have a higher chance of bit rot of course.

Comment: @rakslice your workaround with disk copy local mounts worked really well.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to download the disk images to your Performa 460 and make a fresh copy of the problem disk on other media.

If that works and you want, refresh the apple provided disk with the image to determine if the media itself has failed. Eventually it is likely that the surface of the disc will be unable to retain data.